# Selenium-Java-FireBug : FirePath returns 9 matching nodes where as List<WebElement> is returning 18 elements

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, selenium-webdriver, firebug

FirePath is returning 9 matching nodes where as List is returning 18 elements.

> **OS**:        *Win8 Pro, 64 bit*
>
> **Java**:      jdk1.8.0_77
>
> **Selenium**:  *3.4.0 (selenium-server-standalone)*
>
> **GeckoDriver**:   *0.17.0*
>
> **Browser**:       *Mozilla Firefox 53.0*
>
> **IDE**:       *Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)*
>
> **FireBug**:       *2.0.18*
>
> **URL**:       https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ListEditors/MultiSelect.aspx
>
> **XPATH**:     //table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td

I am trying to get the number of items from a **List Box with Multiple Selection**. When I provide the `xpath` in FireBug/FirePath, it returns me **"9 matching nodes"**.

[image]

Moving forward, through my script, I add the WebElements in a *generic* **List** of type **WebElement** through `findElements` method. Next when I call `size()` method for the `List<WebElement>`, it returns me **`18 Elements`**

### Update:

**(Apologies, I made a mistake in putting up the Question with exact steps while trying to narrow down to the exact problem)**

Here is the complete issue.

### Steps Required:

1. Access the URL.
2. Click on `Selection mode` as `Multiple`
3. From `Phone features` table, I need to select `Blue Tooth`, `Memory Card Slot` and `Touch screen`. The List may vary, so I want to keep it in a `List<String>`.

Here is my script:

```
package demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45065876_keyDown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ListEditors/MultiSelect.aspx");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ContentHolder_lbSelectionMode_I']")).click();
        List<WebElement> selection_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbSelectionMode_DDD_L_LBT']/tbody/tr/td"));
        for (WebElement ele:selection_list)
        {
        if(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML").contentEquals("Multiple"))
            ele.click();
            break;
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContentHolder_lbSelectionMode_DDD_L_LBI1T0")).click();
        List<WebElement> phone_feature_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td"));
        System.out.println("Number of Elements : "+phone_feature_list.size());
        List<String> item_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        item_list.add("Bluetooth");
        item_list.add("Memory Card Slot");
        item_list.add("Touch screen");
        System.out.println("Number of Elements : "+item_list.size());

        for (int i=0; i<phone_feature_list.size(); i++)
        {
            WebElement my_element = phone_feature_list.get(i);
            String innerhtml = my_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
             System.out.println("INNER HTML : "+innerhtml);
            for (int j=0; j<item_list.size(); j++)
            {
                item_list.get(j).contentEquals(innerhtml);
                my_element.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me out to understand whats wrong happening here? Thank you all for all the help.

Comment: for me, firepath is returning 18 elements only.

Comment: For me also, chrome and firepath returns 18

Comment: Ohhh, even XpathChecker returns me 9  here!!!

Comment: @Murthi Firefox & FireBug version?

Comment: @DebanjanB what is your firepath version?. my firepath version is 0.9.7.1.1 and firebug is 2.0.19

Comment: @santhoshkumar Firefox & FireBug version?

Comment: @Murthi Sorry, I don't remember the Firepath version exactly but neither it is shown through Addon-Manager in Firefox. But i guess I installed the updated one. Thanks

Comment: Through `//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td[2]` xpath, Chrome returns 9 but FirePath returns "No matching nodes"

Comment: @santhoshkumar Can you please have a re-look at the updated Question?

Comment: @Murthi Can you please have a re-look at the updated Question?

Comment: @DebanjanB, in phone features i am able to select only one feature at a time. not all three

Comment: @santhoshkumar Thanks, you are right, seems we need to press **Control** additionally :( But did you notice the discrepancy in `Number of Elements` by now, through FireBug & List ?

Comment: Yes, to select multiple, you need to press ctrl

Comment: @Murthi Did you observe the discrepancy in `Number of Elements` by now, through FireBug & Java List<WebElement> ?

Comment: @DebanjanB, The discrepancy is due to, at an instance if we didnt select the multiple, at that time there is a checkbox for each and every phone feature and matching count is 18. But after selecting the multiple, the new page doesnt have the check box so the matching count is 9.

Comment: @DebanjanB, i think like the if case for multiple is not getting executed and multiple is not actually getting selected. So the script might have executed with check boxes for phone feature and thus 18.

Comment: @santhoshkumar I have provided the code block, would you mind a try at your end? **Java List<WebElement>** is returning **18** thats my actual issue. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, In chrome its working as expected. Number of Elements : 9
Number of Elements : 3
INNER HTML : 3G
INNER HTML : Bluetooth
INNER HTML : Infrared
INNER HTML : Memory Card Slot
INNER HTML : QWERTY keyboard
INNER HTML : Touch screen
INNER HTML : USB
INNER HTML : Voice Dialing
INNER HTML : Wi-Fi Update: Firefox also works good for me.

Comment: @santhoshkumar Thanks a ton :) I am speechless. The client wants the code to be `W3C` compliant. So `Firefox` is the only way out for me.

Comment: @DebanjanB.., Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I did try it on Chrome, shows 9 elements. But I have to get it working on Firefox as per **W3C** compliance. But again, the last mile remains to select multiple items (++Control button).

Comment: @DebanjanB, for me firefox also works fine. I am using latest driver and browser. For holding the ctrl key, before the last for loop, make use of robot class to key down the ctrl and after the for loop(all the required elements will be clicked inside the for loop) we can key up the ctrl key using same robot class.

Comment: @santhoshkumar Thanks for the input. I will surely get back to you.

Comment: @santhoshkumar With some changes in my code Mozilla & Chrome behaves the same now. But still unable to make multiple selection through `Actions` and `Robot` Class. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Note that your versions of Firefox and Firebug are outdated. Latest versions are Firefox 54.0.1 and Firebug 2.0.19. Having said that, please note that Firebug is discontinued and [won't work anymore once multiprocess Firefox is enabled](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/), but definitely starting from Firefox 57.0 (which [only supports WebExtensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/)).

Comment: @SebastianZartner Thanks a lot for your guidance. Actually, I need to get some time to check out the next `Stable GA` version of `Mozilla Firefox` post 53.0. Then I will consider upgrading :) Yes I saw the multi-process Firefox thread. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It take a second or two for the site to refresh. The `xpath`

```
"//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td"
```

includes those checkboxes so you are getting 18 results. You can wait until there is different number of results

```
List<WebElement> phone_feature_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'dxeT')]"));
int size = phone_feature_list.size();

// choose an option from the dropdown

// wait for the size to change
while ((phone_feature_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ContentHolder_lbFeatures_LBT']/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'dxeT')]"))).size() == size);

System.out.println("Number of Elements : " + phone_feature_list.size());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please look at the updated Question once again. (Apologies, previously I made a mistake in putting up the Question with exact steps while trying to narrow down to the exact problem)

Comment: Well, your Answer gave me some fresh ideas and new dimensions to workout a solution to overcome this issue. Thanks a ton !!!